# Facebook pictures and videos not showing up in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash, facebook

I've been using ubuntu for over a year and this is the first time i get this problem. Pictures and videos in facebook don't load after some minutes i've opened the browser (tried googlechrome, chromium and firefox). 
In firefox i get a message saying i have to update flash player, but it is updated
I even tried running chrome and firefox in the Live-CD but it's still the same
In windows everything seems to be fine

Comment: Please fully update your system before anything else: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I already did that

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: None, only in firefox. It says i need to update flash player, but i have it updated

Comment: I meant errors during the update... And, by the way since you're insisting on that, how do you installed Flash support and why do you think it's updated?

Comment: No errors during the update, i installed adobe-flashplugin and i checked in the adobe page. I thought the flash player came with integrated flashplayer, but there seems to be the same issue